# How to store menu items in database with a List of child menu items

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, ef-code-first, .net-6.0

I'm using .NET 6 code first approach, and I'm trying to store my navigation menu in the database. I created the MenuItem table with the following fields:

[image: menu item model]

How do I go about storing a menu items parent, and a parent menu item's children? Don't I need to create a foreign key field? You can see I created the 2 lists in the model currently, with TopLevelItems and Children Lists of other Menu Items.

I want a menu item to have the possibility of having children, or parent menu items... For example, About > Services; would be the About page as the Top Level Menu Item > and the Services page would be the child Menu Item... If there was also About > Sponsors, Sponsors would be another child menu item.... So Services and Sponsors would be Children items stored in the Children List field. TopLeveItems would honestly always just store all top level menu items.. Home, About, Contact.... etc.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you actually need navigation as DB records, the difficulty lies in the multiple recursive levels. By keeping track of all parents for a single record, you'll have to think about how you keep track of the n dimensions that introduces.

For example:
Services > Consulting > Software > .NET

Let's look at the .NET record. Will its parents be tracked as single items ["Services", "Consulting", "Software"] or will you track the objects including THEIR parents each? That would be pretty redundant and bad for data normalization.

I think you should only refer to a single parent object, and go from there if you need to iterate higher up. Always try to model in a way that data is not present in more than one place at a time. Otherwise you'd also have to update all child records once parent records get updated.

By keeping track of just one optional parent Id, you should be able to deduct the full tree upwards.

Second issue is then; how will you efficiently crawl this table to build your navigation? Because as of now, you need the full dataset in order to build and deduct hierarchy. Some caching might be a good idea. But to be honest, I've rarely seen navigation being stored in an SQL table because of its frequent reads, rare changes and overall belonging in the view layer of an app.

Comment: That is a good point... I don't think I need a child items field or top level items field as long as I keep track of the parent menu item...

So for the parent id field, I could do it like so:

public  MenuItem ParentItem
public int ParentItemId as Foreign Key

Comment: @JakeFromStateFarm Usually a many-to-one relation needs e.g. a List<> on the many side and just an int Id on the one side of the relation. However, in this case it's a bit weird because a parent can also be a child and vice versa. That's why my first suggestion would be to keep it simple and "link the chain" by just tracking parent id. Since that relation brings you to the next link. If you want to fully model the objects of parents and children in separate lists, perhaps a separate relation table is better - otherwise this table/entity could contain lots of duplicate data.

Answer (score 1):

Your **database table** structure to store a hierarchy of navigation records should look something like this (url omitted for brevity):

```
(PK)    menu_id int
(FK,IX) menu_parent_id int
        display_text varchar(100)
```

DDL statements to create the DB table:

```
CREATE TABLE navigation
    ([menu_id] int, 
     [menu_parent_id] int, 
     [display_text] varchar(100),
    CONSTRAINT [PK_navigation] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (
    [menu_id] ASC
))
;

INSERT INTO navigation
VALUES
    (1, 0, 'About'),
    (2, 1, 'Services'),
    (3, 2, 'Consulting'),
    (4, 3, 'Software'),
    (5, 4, '.NET'),
    (6, 1, 'Sponsors' )
;

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_menu_parent_id] ON [dbo].[navigation]
(
    [menu_parent_id] ASC
);

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[navigation]  WITH NOCHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_menu_parent_id] FOREIGN KEY([menu_parent_id])
REFERENCES [dbo].[navigation] ([menu_id])
```

menu_parent_id contains the id of a childs parent and is a foreign key that references menu_id.  For example, data for the menu you described would look like the following:

```
menu_id   menu_parent_id  display_text
-------   --------------  --------------------
      1                0  About
      2                1  Services
      3                2  Consulting
      4                3  Software
      5                4  .NET
      6                1  Sponsors
```

The table above describes the following hierarchies:

```
About > Services > Consulting > Software > .NET
About > Sponsors
```

... and can support an unlimited number of child-parent items.   Top level items have a menu_parent_id of zero.

With regard to your .NET code, the entire table (or any subset thereof) can be loaded into a Dictionary of menu_item's keyed by menu_id, i.e.:

```
public class menu_item
{
   public int menu_id {get; set;}
   public int menu_parent_id {get; set;}
   public String display_text { get; set; }
}


// Dictionary key is menu_id ...
Dictionary<int, menu_item> menu_items;

menu_items = new Dictionary<int, menu_item>();

// Query DB to load all menu items or any subset into a Dictionary ...
```

Once the dictionary is populated you have fast access to any menu item via menu_id.

Hope that helps.